# Unable to connect to wireless networks after 12.04 automatic update

Tags: wireless, updates

I have downloaded and installed Ubuntu 12.04 x64 and ran automatic update.
After which though i see them but am unable to create or connect to any wireless networks (AD-HOC or existing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command to unblock all wireless devices:

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Comment: yes .. everything was working fine before the update

Comment: please tell what more details do you want .. i'll provide .. i am unable to exactly figure our what and how to format this question

Comment: not sure. Try `initctl start network-manager` looks like there are nm issues with precise